# Trouble with Ajax post in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I need three dependent drop down menus. When a user selects the first menu (market environment), then I need ajax to send that selection to my view in django so I can query SQL to get a list of currencies and populate the second list. In firebug, I keep getting the following error:

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /Tplots/ajax_curr/"'mkt'"
```

I also notice that my Post is empty so I think something is going wrong with my ajax code and I'm not sure whats wrong. Any help would be great.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function get_currency(){
$('#id_mkt').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/Tplots/ajax_curr/",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    })
 })
   })
</script>

<div align="center">
<h1>Swap Curves</h1>
<form action="{% url 'Tplots:swapFig' %}" method = "post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.mkt}}
{{form.curr}}
{{form.horizon}}
<input type = "submit" value="Go To" />
</form>
```

view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def ajax_curr(request): 
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_mkt = MktEnv.objects.get(mkt=request.POST['mkt'])
        #selected_mkt = request.POST.get('mkt','')
        conn = pyodbc.connect('abcd')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        sql_raw = r'''
            select currency from market_env_detail
            where mkt_env_id=%s
            and idx = 1''' % (selected_mkt)
        cursor.execute(sql_raw)
        xx = cursor.fetchall()
        currencyL = []
        for items in xx:
            x = str(items[0])
            currencyL.append(x)
        curr = list(set(currencyL))
    json = simplejson.dumps(curr)
    print json
    return HttpResponse(json, mimetype="application/json")
```

forms.py

```
class CurrencyForm(forms.Form):
   Env_Choices = [('', '-- Choose a Environment --'), ] + [(m.mkt, m.mkt) for m in MktEnv.objects.all()]
   Curr_Choices = [('', '--Choose a Currency --'),]+[(c.curr, c.curr) for c in CurrencyAjax.objects.all()]
   Horizon_Choices = [('', '--Choose a Horizon --'),] +[(h.hid, h.hid) for h in HorIdAjax.objects.all()]
   mkt = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Env_Choices)
   curr = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Curr_Choices)
   horizon = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Horizon_Choices)
```

**Edit:**

I'm trying to put the data into the second dropdown using this success function but all my values become blank. Don't know why.

```
success: function(data) {
            for(var i =0; i<data.length; i++) {
                var item=data[i];
                $('#curr').append(
                    $("<option></option>").val(item.Id).html(item.Name));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should use `.text(item.Name)`. Html overwrites the `<option></option>`. If should try [this library](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) (jquery.chained.js), it will help you code chained selects easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not sending POST data. You are missing the `data` parameter.

```
var data = $(this).parents('form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/Tplots/ajax_curr/",
    data: data,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!

If I need to add that data to the second drop down menu would the code just be:

success: function(data) {
    $('#id_curr').append(data);
   },

Comment: I edited my original post to make it easier to read my question about adding the data to my second menu.

Comment: @vdesai as you are sending the csrf_token  in the request to django  maybe you can consider remove csrf_exempt decorator